# Xcode 6 not generating .h file

Tags: ios, xcode

I upgraded to Xcode 6, now when I add a new Objective-C file it does not automatically create a .h file.. Am I missing something? Has anyone see this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Header files used to be created automatically when you create a .m file. When upgrading to Xcode 6, sometimes the "automatically create header file" box becomes unchecked. Make sure this box is checked when creating a new .m file.

Answer (score 0):

This only works with CocoaTouch classes, it looks like it does not work with regular .m/Obj-C classes